# How to get scored combination of features

Tags: feature-selection, text-mining

My data looks like this (F=Features)

```
        F1     F2     F3     F4     F5     F6     F7     F8....
ID1     0.67   0.76   0.3    0.54   0.21   0.88   0.97   0.45....
ID2     0.76   0.68   0.10   0.45   0.12   0.44   0.79   0.54....
ID3     0.67   0.76   0.3    0.54   0.21   0.88   0.68   0.76....
ID4     0.67   0.10   0.3    0.45   0.3    0.88   0.97   0.45....
...
...
...
```

I have about 40 features (I have just put 8 here). If I set a threshold for, say 4 features, what I am looking for is a combination of 4 features which, together, are most relevant and significant in the dataset. I need some kind of score that measures how good a combination of features is. This is what I meant by the confidence score (or whatever score we may call it). So instead of selecting 1 feature I want to select a combination of 4 features. For example.

```
F1-F4-F9-F12 = 0.92
F2-F3-F7-F6 = 0.85
F5-F3-F4-F8 = 0.667
```

Here, F1-F4 is not subtraction. I am just attaching the two features together. The scores above, I do not know how to get it. That is my question? So I do not know what kind of a test to use or can be used.

How can I go about it? Thanks

Comment: @yO2gO What would/should your confidence score reflect? What is the purpose of the analysis? (You added the `feature-selection` tag, but what are those features?)

Comment: @chl this is from the biology domain. For each ID, how important each feature is, is the score (tf-idf) given to it in the sample table above. The confidences reflects, statistically how significant the combination of features are in the whole dataset and not just for one ID.

Comment: @yO2gO (1) What do you mean by tf and idf? (2) I checked your example for no pair of F5 and F3 values holds that `F5-F3 = 0.667`, could you explain this?

Comment: @GaBorgulya The values in the table are calculated using tf-idf (term frequency - inverse document frequency). When I say F5-F3=0.667, I mean the two features (F5 and F3) together are 0.667 significant

Comment: @yO2gO So this is text mining (or information retrieval). And you use the `-` sign to group features into combinations of features, not subtraction. What do you mean by “0.667 significant”, is this a p value of a significance test? What kind of test?

Comment: @GaBorgulya This is post the text mining step. And `-` is not subtraction, it is to attach. What kind of test is my question? I want a test that will give me a ranked list. Say from the 40 features I need a combination of best features. I want a score for the "best". I am looking for a test for this.

Comment: @yO2gO So 0.667 is not related to [significance tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significance_test), but you want some kind of score that measures how good a combination of features is? What do you mean by good and “best”? In what case do you want the combination {F1, F4, F9} be assigned a higher score than {F5, F3}? What's the meaning of a higher score?

Comment: I'm not sure this question deserves *so many downvotes*. Although it lacks some information, some clarifications are given as comments, upon request -- @yO2gO, maybe you could now update your question and just add a rough definition of what you think of or expect from such a *confidence score*?

Comment: @GaBorgulya You are right. I need some kind of score that measures how good a combination of features is. Good/best is the most significant in the dataset. `{F1, F4, F9}` should be assigned a higher score than `{F5, F3}` based on how each of the features are scored in the dataset.

Comment: @chl Thanks. I have updated the question. I was/am unsure on how to frame the question. But I hope this updated version helps you guys help me better. Thanks

Comment: @yO2gO I'm still unsure how you mean “[best] combination of features … is the most significant in the dataset”. A way I can think about this is that you want to select a subset of features that contain most of the information contained in the dataset. In other words a good combination of features predicts all other features with good accuracy. You may also want to select the smallest number of such features. Is this what you want?

Comment: @GaBorgulya Yes, this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand (see comments to the original question) you want to select a subset of the features by two criteria:

1. the subset covers most of the information content of the dataset,
2. the subset includes as few features as possible.

The paper [*Variable selection in large environmental data sets using principal components analysis* by King and Jackson in Environmetrics, 1999](http://j.mp/gYJ4sn) compares the methods for this problem.